# Ajax dúvidas em atualizações

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Bom dia! gostaria de saber como funciona a tecnologia Ajax, se é possível eu fazer um código em php e chama-lo através de um ajax, tipo uma consulta, eu colocaria o arquivo de resposta em uma página e o php em outra com ajax? Como funciona, poderiam me explicar? Não achei muito bem na internet. Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resumindo bastante, é quando você, no caso, faz requisições para se comunicar com os scripts do lado do servidor utilizando requisições HTTP.

Esse script do lado do servidor no seu caso, é um código em PHP.

A vantagem da utilização é que através dessa requisição você não precisa recarregar a sua página.

Existem vários jeitos de se fazer, mas um dos jeitos mais comuns é utilizando  jquery, conforme o código abaixo:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST', // Aqui é o método HTTP
    dataType: 'json', // Aqui é o formato do retorno do script php logo abaixo
    url: 'salvar.php', // Este é o seu script PHP do lado do servidor
    data: dados, // Aqui são os dados que você vai enviar pelo metodo notificado acima, no caso POST, para o seu script salvar.php
    success: function(response) { // aqui é o tratamento do retorno do script salvar.php. O success indica que o script retornou o código 200, ou seja, foi encontrado e executado sem erros
          location.reload();
     }
});
```

Comment: Obrigado! Em uma página de administradores é bom fazer uso deste tipo de método?

Comment: Depende do caso , amigo, não tem regra fixa pra isso não. Mas um ajax mal feito causa lentidão. Abraços